# Каким образом можно разместить тег a по центру?

Tags: html, css

Я знаю, что можно сделать с помощью db + m0, auto или тега center, но тогда bg растягивается на весь экран. Можно ли это обойти?

```css
/* contact */
.contacts {
  padding-top: 90px;
}

.cont__title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #070707;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.cont__disc {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 27px;
  color: #070707;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.cont__btn {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 23px 8px 23px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cont_social {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.social {
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.cont__rec {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts">
      <div class="cont__title">Contacts</div>
      <div class="cont__disc">
        Want to know more or just chat? <br />
        You are welcome!
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="cont__btn">Send message</a>
      <div class="cont_social">
        <img src="img/LinkedIn.svg" alt=":(" class="social" />
        <img src="img/Instargam.svg" alt=":(" class="social" />
        <img src="img/Behance.svg" alt=":(" class="social" />
        <img src="img/Dribble.svg" alt=":(" />
      </div>
      <div class="cont__rec">
        Like me on <br />
        LinkedIn, Instagram, Behance, Dribble
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Добавьте `text-align: center;` к `.contacts` и будет вам счастье.

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался! Нужно всего лишь обернуть тег a в любой другой (div например) и уже к нему применить стиль text-align: center;